# Why is TypeScript not letting me do a single comparison condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dom, frontend

The error is straightforward: `Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Ref<number>'.`
But the fact that I cannot make a comparison between 2 numbers is absurd, here's the code, I'm quite new with Typescript, so some help would be very appreciated:

```
  // Scroll logic:
    let lastScroll = ref<number>(0)

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const body = document.body
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const currentScroll = window.scrollY

        if (currentScroll <= 0) {
          body.classList.remove('scroll-up')
        }

        if (
          currentScroll > lastScroll &&
          !body.classList.contains('scroll-down')
        ) {
          body.classList.remove('scroll-up')
          body.classList.add('scroll-down')
        }
        if (
          currentScroll < lastScroll &&
          body.classList.contains('scroll-down')
        ) {
          body.classList.remove('scroll-down')
          body.classList.add('scroll-up')
        }

        lastScroll = currentScroll
      })
    }
```

the error is in the if() comparison:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ref is not a number. Calling `ref` returns an object. [See here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref):

> Takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable ref object, which has a single property .value that points to the inner value.
>
> ```
> const count = ref(0)
> console.log(count.value) // 0
>
> count.value++
> console.log(count.value) // 1
> ```

For clarity, rename `lastScroll` to `lastScrollRef`. Then change all references of `lastScroll` to `lastScrollRef.value`. For example

```
currentScroll > lastScroll &&
```

should change to

```
currentScrollRef.value > lastScroll &&
```

and so on.

Comment: True, but a suffix doesn't add much clarity. Then there can be a plethora of computeds that are mostly refs that can't be assigned. A way to reduce cognitive load a lot is to use `unref` for safety (there's a guarantee that `unref(lastScroll)` is needed when a value is primitive but reactive), and prefer `reactive` instead of `ref` for objects where practical. Then the remnant `refs` are not just vars that hold local state but the ones that require ref pattern, notably DOM refs, can be suffixed to designate their purpose